# Removing QGraphicsSimpleTextItem from QGraphicsView's Scene not working

Tags: python, pyqt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicstextitem

As part of my pet project, I would need to add & remove text from QGraphicsScene. However for some reason I am unable to remove QGraphicsSimpleTextItems in the same manner as one would remove polygons, namely creating them with a pointer, and using scene.removeItem(item_name).

Please find a minimum reproducible example below to replicate the problem that I'm having with removing QGraphicsSimpleTextItems from the screen.

Where am I going wrong? Thanks!

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush,QPen,QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsSimpleTextItem



def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    items = {}
    colors_rgb = [[8, 247, 254], [254, 83, 187], [255, 170, 1], [86, 10, 134], [117, 213, 253],
                  [255, 34, 129], [128, 255, 0], [2, 184, 166]]

    positions_ = [[100,200],[10,200],[120,503],[150,400],[300,150],[150,230],[530,20],[400,200]]
    text_ =["textitem_1","textitem_2","textitem_3","textitem_4","textitem_5","textitem_6","textitem_7","textitem_8"]
    scene = QGraphicsScene()
    view = QGraphicsView(scene)
    for i in range(len(text_)):
        txt_ = QGraphicsSimpleTextItem(text_[i])
        txt_.setPos(positions_[i][0],positions_[i][1])
        txt_.setPen(QPen(QColor(0,0,0)))
        txt_.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(colors_rgb[i][0],colors_rgb[i][1],colors_rgb[i][2])))
        items[i] = scene.addItem(txt_)
        scene.removeItem(items[i])


    view.resize(640, 480)
    view.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Edit**

I found that if add the QGraphicsSimpleTextItem itself to dictionary, instead of using a pointer, I am able to remove the items without a problem. Why is this the case?

```
    for i in range(len(text_)):
    txt_ = QGraphicsSimpleTextItem(text_[i])
    txt_.setPos(positions_[i][0],positions_[i][1])
    txt_.setPen(QPen(QColor(0,0,0)))
    txt_.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(colors_rgb[i][0],colors_rgb[i][1],colors_rgb[i][2])))
    scene.addItem(txt_)
    items[i] = txt_


for i in range(len(text_)):
    scene.removeItem(items.get(i))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the basic shape `add*()` functions return an item (`addRect()`, `addLine()`, etc), since they are used to *create* new items.

[`addItem()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#addItem) adds an *existing* item, and it returns `None` (there's no point in returning an object that is the argument of the function), then the problem is here (I added a print statement to show the result):

```
items[i] = scene.addItem(txt_)
print(items[i])
```

As you can see, you're actually adding `None` as dictionary values, and then trying to remove *nothing* from the scene, so the items actually remain on the scene.

You need to add the item to the dictionary, as you did in your second example.